Adding an output to a SMPS transformer
I'm working on this SMPS circuit (recommended by STMicroelectronics). If you have any suggestions for improvement feel free to comment that.

As you can see, the output has 12.05V, but I want to add another one, with 15v, can this be done doing this circuit, and adding the corresponding turns to the secondary?

What I would have to consider doing this? Is there a more efficient way to do this?
EDIT
The circuit as I said, was generated by ST. You can make it yourself in this link:
STmicroelectronics Designer
My values chosen were:

Vmin=180V
Vmax=250V
Output voltage: 12V
Output current: 10A
Frecuency: 50Hz



If you have any suggestions for improvement feel free to comment

The original has a 0 volt and +12 volt output port. The proposed new circuit has an extra winding connected to 0 volts and producing +15 volts. You might consider stacking a 12 volt and a 3 volt winding or, making a 15 volt winding with a 12 volt "centre"-tap. It's far fewer secondary turns of course.
Then you need to decide whether it's more important to regulate the +12 volt output (as shown currently) and let the +15 volt output find its own level or vice versa.
Or you could convert to 15 volt (regulated) and use a buck converter to make 12 volts.

Probably the best way will be stacking more turns to the existing winding, because the output current is 10 A, using a converter will be impossible. I forgot to mention that one  will be used, both at the same time can't. What do you mean by finding its own level? Let's say that 15 volt output is being used, and 12 volt output is the one regulated, if the voltage of the 15 V output decreases, the same has to happen in the 12V one, so the feedback should increase the PWM, I'm wrong?

If you only need one of the output voltages at a time, why not only switch a single feedback resistor? You will get either 12v or 15v from the same output.

@samuelmattio the 15 volt won't quite be as regulated as the 12 volt line but, it will be better with stacked windings that are closely coupled.

How I should design the transformer and feedback circuit for that? Design transformer for 15v and change ROUT_H?

@Andyaka Clear... What do you think about making only one winding and changing ROUT_H?

You can leave it as it is if it's connected to the 12 volt output @samuelmattio

So make only 1 output, and change with some type of circuit the resistance of the feedback?

You need two outputs right?

Not necessarily two outputs, it can be one that can change voltage from 15V to 12V.

In that case, yes you can use one winding for two different output levels by changing the feedback components.

@samuelmattio if we are done here, please take note of this: What should I do when someone answers my question. If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.
